# Scrampled python script after pc crash

Tags: python, ubuntu, gedit

so i was running a script when suddenly my laptop froze and i had to force shutdown.

on restarting, i discovered the script file is now containing scrambled text. All my lines of codes gone. The other scripts in the same directory are still unchanged.

when i tried opening the script in gedit i got error

> invalid byte sequence in conversion input

but in Atom editor it contains scrambled text.

```
(s�)I�IC��\��>�*c0k�eI��5�U��#LX�+�f���l6��_��E"��,c��Cc��#�(ecE�b��;¨�Q:y�Ʉ?0N�J�Pw�b߉B�p��)E�W���W��CV:�z��V=��4����b@�W�A(��P��v8�ͣR�>g]��Uۧױ�3�q�{
```

�"Q��;@����hR�����Jݡ�

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Are you using git or any other vc?

Comment: its gone, maybe atom has saved something in the history

Comment: no i'm not using git. @user2263572

Comment: @juliusmh, how do i check the atom history

Comment: Do you have a compiled version of the file?  Would have a .pyc extension.

Comment: no i dont have it.

Comment: Not very sure @pythoncoder but if you find something you can post here to let others know. Would be interesting to see. Can you upload a raw version of the corrupted script somewhere so people can investigate further?

Comment: @juliusmh too late. i deleted it and rewrote from scratch. very strange event i must say. luckily it was around 150 lines of code. still imagining what if it was say a couple thousand lines.